# How do I edit the xfce4.12 Whisker Menu globally for all users on Ubuntu Studio 18.04.4 LTS via a root file manager or terminal?

Tags: command-line, xfce, root, ubuntu-studio, whisker

I want to edit the Xfce4.12 Whisker Menu running on Ubuntu Studio 18.04.4 LTS in "/". I want to edit the categories like: "All", "Audio Production", etc using either the XML files or whatever files are needed to edit the menu and I also want to create new entries. I want to do it in the root directory because I want the changes to take global effect for all users and new users created in the OS. I also want to change and/or create new entries in the left column of the menu where the entries are "Web Browser", "File Manager", etc. The next thing I would like to change is the column width between the two columns. The last thing I would like to change and/or create new entries for is the bar at the bottom of the menu where it has the "All Settings", "Lock Screen", and the "Log Out" buttons. I want to edit these files from a root file manager or from a text based terminal only. I don't want to do it from the GUI. Where are the file locations I need and which/what ways do I do all this? Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was not an LTS release for the Ubuntu Studio team. Please see http://ubuntustudio.org/2018/05/clarification-on-non-lts-status-of-ubuntu-studio-18-04/